# How are aar libraries handled on installation/use?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to understand how `aar` libraries work on installation and on running. I have searched everywhere and the information is scarce. The `aar` library I got has 4 `.SO` files for multiple `ABI`s.

I have used an explorer app on my phone and navigated to the app folder (after installation) `/data/app/packagepath` and found a folder named lib with a single `.SO` file which is the one for my device's `ABI`.

Am I right to assume that the Android device picks the `.SO` file that is relative to it ignoring the rest. Then, on launch the app would use the `.SO` file from the `/data/app/packagepath` folder ignoring the aar file included with the `APK` altogether. So, the `aar` file is like a resource that is used only one time and on installation only?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't mention if you've configured: [Multiple APK support](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks) or [App Signing by Google Play](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#app-signing-google-play)

Comment: Hello, Morrison. I was talking in general. No multiple APK. No google signing. I just create a signed APK (no bundles either). Then, install it on my devices.

Answer (score 1):

Android Archive (AAR files) should be thought of as dependency delivery packaging rather bundled directly in a APK.

[APKs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_application_package) themselves make no distinction in assets and resources as they all belong to one app, so all of the components are merged into their respective directories.

Before AAR, trying to integrate a third party library meant that the integrating developer had to handle the merge process which meant needing to keep track of resources like images, JNI binaries, and deal with dependency conflicts.

As described in [the documentation for Android library](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library) some of the features of the AAR processing pipeline include:

- Resource merge conflicts
- Each library module creates its own R class
- A library module may include its own ProGuard configuration file

As to why there is only one `.so` file, I would expect to see all ABIs in the APK, and the system would only install the appropriate platform binary libraries for the device.

Actually at install time, Ahead Of Time (AOT) compilation occurs, see [Android Runtime (ART) and Dalvik](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik) for more details.